# Enable Disable Cron in PHP code

Tags: php, linux, cron

I want a script to enable or disable cron in php code.

Lets say in some situation, I want to enable cron.

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/cron.php
```

And in other situation, I want to disable cron.

```
#*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/user/cron.php
```

So how can I do this in PHP code?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: I have integrated Drupal with Alfresco. When content is added or updated in drupal, It is created or updated in Alfresco. It is running perfectly. But when alfresco server is down, I want to enable cron to check if alfresco server is on or not. Once alfresco server is on, i want to move all content in alfresco and disable cron

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you'd leave the cron task itself on all the time, and have code in `/home/user/cron.php` to detect the situations in which it should or should not do something.